# Agda error: Importing module IO using the --guardedness flag from a module which does not

Tags: agda, agda-mode

I have this example taken from the [Agda documentation](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.2/getting-started/a-taste-of-agda.html#building-an-executable-agda-program)

```
module hello-world-prog where

open import IO

main : Main
main = run (putStrLn "Hello, World!")
```

But when I run Ctrl+c, Ctrl+x, Ctrl+c and enter GHC, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\myname\Documents\Agda\hello-world-prog.agda:3,1-15
Importing module IO using the --guardedness flag from a module
which does not.
when scope checking the declaration
  open import IO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory: the `IO` module has the `--guardedness` flag, but your module doesn't and Agda consider this to be an error.

You can make it type check by adding

```
{-# OPTIONS --guardedness #-}
```

to the top of the file.

If you're curious why guardedness is now turned off by default, you can find details in [this](https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/4908) issue.